# Javascript :: generate new variable in a closure and use it through an object instance

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest, closures

H! I have to fetch JSON data from a remote file and grab its values into variables accessibles by the  instance of the object I created "v".

With this code I get "undefined"

(I'm trying to minimize as much as possible antipatterns)

```
var Func = function (url) {

    this.url = url;
};

Func.prototype.fetch = function () {

    // fetching the JSON content
    var res = new XMLHttpRequest();
    res.open('GET', this.url, true);
    res.onreadystatechange = function () {

        if (res.readyState == 4) {
            if (res.status == 200) {

                // this is the object I want access from outside
                var obj = JSON.parse(res.responseText);
                this.ip = obj.ip;
            }
        }
        res.send(null);
    };
};

var v = new Func("http://ip.jsontest.com/?callback=showMyIP");
v.fetch();

//now I get "undefined"
console.log("ip " + v.ip);
```

I hope I've been clear.
Could someone help me with this please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `res.open` is asynchronous call. You will not get data immediately. Execution will reach `console.log("ip " + v.ip);` before your `onreadystatechange` code will be executed. You can easily check this by inserting `console.log` or using breakpoints. You need to rewrite your code with callbacks:

```
var Func = function (url) {

    this.url = url;
};

Func.prototype.fetch = function (onready) {

    // fetching the JSON content
    var res = new XMLHttpRequest();
    res.open('GET', this.url, true);
    var that = this;
    res.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (res.readyState == 4) {
            if (res.status == 200) {

                // this is the object I want access from outside
                var obj = JSON.parse(res.responseText);
                that.ip = obj.ip;
                onready();
            }
        }            
    };
    res.send(null);
};

var v = new Func("http://ip.jsontest.com/");
v.fetch(function () {
    console.log("ip " + v.ip);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Using your suggestion it seems that the script stop executing before "res.onreadystatechange = function () { ..." so it doesn't return the console.log

Comment: @ant0nio you should not do send inside onreadystatechange, also `http://ip.jsontest.com/?callback=showMyIP` doesn't return JSON but callback. I updated my answer;

Comment: this almost works! The v.ip variable in the console.log returns undefined.

Comment: @ant0nio you should learn how to debug things. This inside onreadystatechange callback is actually `res` object, so you need to preserve needed this, see edit.

Answer (score 0):

Since `fetch` is async, you cannot get the value of `v.ip` right after calling the function `v.fetch()`. To see the value, you have to console.log in the callback.

```
var Func = function (url) {

        this.url = url;
    };

    Func.prototype.fetch = function () {

        // fetching the JSON content
        var res = new XMLHttpRequest();
        res.open('GET', this.url, true);
        res.onreadystatechange = function () {

            if (res.readyState == 4) {
                if (res.status == 200) {

                    // this is the object I want access from outside
                    var obj = JSON.parse(res.responseText);
                    this.ip = obj.ip;
                    console.log(this.ip); // WORKS HERE
                }
            }
            res.send(null);
        };
    };

    var v = new Func("http://ip.jsontest.com/?callback=showMyIP");
    v.fetch();

    //now I get "undefined" because the function is async and is not done putting the value in this.ip.
    console.log("ip " + v.ip);
```

Comment: Hi! This works pretty good,  but that's not what I would like to do in my case.
What I want to do is to execute the console.log from the outside of the constructor. Thanks anyway :)